# How to access Backbone objects from console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

A Backbone Collection and some Views are created in the return function of `click()` as shown in the code snippet below.

**Problem:** How can I access backbone.js objects like the Collection `productList` using the Javascript console? `this.productList` does not return anything, so I believe `productList` is not a direct child of the `window` object. How then should I create `productList` collection?

**JS Code**

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        console.log('do something');
    }, function() {

        this.productList = new ProductCollection();
        var self = this;
        self.productListView = new ProductListView({ collection: self.productList });
        this.productList.fetch({
            data: {gender: 'men'},
            processData: true
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now in this case you cannot can everything is in an anonymous function so you cant access it after the function has executed. This is anyways not the right way to do things, or not the backbone way.

This is how i generally do stuff,
create a central namespace like app and then create all the models, collections and views to that namespace as

```
window.App = {
   //model
   Curve : {},
   //collection
   CurveManager : {},
   //view
   Views : {},
   //controller
   Controller : {}
}
```

plus i think that you should take care of the click event from a backbone view itself then it would be comparatively easier for you to visualize things. For example in http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html take a look at the AppView events. that should make things much more clearer.

here is that part of the code

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#todoapp"),
    statsTemplate: _.template($('#stats-template').html()),
    events: {
      "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter",
      "click #clear-completed": "clearCompleted",
      "click #toggle-all": "toggleAllComplete"
    },

    .
    . // more code in between
    .

    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!this.input.val()) return;

      Todos.create({title: this.input.val()});
      this.input.val('');
    },
```

I generally look at other peoples code on github and try to learn how they do things and how things should be done, i suggest you do the same. It helps a lot :) The todoapp annotated source is really clean and pretty easy to understand.

Comment: Here is one good link i found . http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/15/workflow-in-backbone-apps-triggering-view-events-from-dom-events/

Answer (score 0):

You could attach productList to the `window` object.

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        console.log('do something');
    }, function() {

        window.productList = new ProductCollection();
        var self = this;
        self.productListView = new ProductListView({ collection: self.productList });
        window.productList.fetch({
            data: {gender: 'men'},
            processData: true
        });

    });
});
```

But you'd be better off refactoring your code like @avk said so `submit_btn` was part of a Backbone view.

Regardless of what's going on, since `this` in that instance refers to the closure in which your code is running, it's not going to be accessible until you export it to an externally available object.

Comment: Yes I should follow @avk's advice. In this case, is `var self = this;` still needed? Or do i replace `self.` with `window` in the case of your example code?